# jquery image replace timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a collection of jpeg images in an html document which I'd like to simply  hide/show in a sequence: img0.jpg, img1.jpg, img2.jpg, img3.jpg etc...essentially a simple image swapper, swapping each image for the next every 0.5 seconds. However, as added features I'd like:

- the first image to remain visible for 1 second
- the second image to remain visible for 1.5 seconds
- the sequence to loop, starting again at the third image and not the first.
  Any ideas?!
  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

this is what I use on a couple of my sites

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/lite/

but he's right you could have found that with google ;)